# Meaning of #use directive in legacy VC6 C code

Tags: c-preprocessor, visual-c++-6

While resurrecting old, VC6 code, I ran into the following

```
#use "default.h"
#use aasc.lib
#use aascz0.lib
```

I have have not been able to find documentation for `#use`. I think the directive is a combination of `#include` (as in `#use "default.h"` meaning `#include "default.h"`) and a linkage editor directive (as in `#use aasc.lib` and `#use aascz0.lib` being propagated to the object file as maybe a `/DYNAMICBASE "aasc.lib" "aascz0.lib"`), but I'm not confident.

In any case, the compiler (Visual Studio 2017 Community) rejects the statements with a C1021 diagnostic ("invalid processor command 'use'").

Can any "archeologists" shed light on the `#use` directive?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't VC6 code.  Microsoft Visual C 6.0 documentation is still available on the web, and it makes no mention of `#use` directives.  My guess is that you're looking at Dynamic C 6.0 code.

Dynamic C is a product of Rabbit Semiconductors, which originally was a division of Z-World, Inc but was sold off in 2006 to Digi International.  This will probably become a dead link fairly quickly, but [here](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/019-0125K.pdf) is a Dynamic C manual; grab that while you can... it documents `#use`.

In particular, `default.h` has a set of `#use` directives for each Rabbit product.  `AASC.LIB` is the Abstract Application-Level Serial Communications library; `AASCZ0.LIB` contains support functions for built-in `Z0` functions, according to [this](https://www.naic.edu/~phil/td/function_reference_0190082_d.pdf) much older reference that seems targeted to Zilog Z180 and Dynamic C version 6.x.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you. Your answer saved me a lot of effort.